# Fill in textarea within <noscripts> tags with python mechanize

Tags: python, textarea, screen-scraping, mechanize

I'm having a problem with mechanize registering a text area field from within a  tag.

Example URL: http://www.gegononta.gr/register.php

Code:

```
mech = mechanize.Browser()
url = "http://www.gegononta.gr/register.php"
response = mech.open(url)

mech.select_form(nr=1)
mech.form.set_all_readonly(False)

print mech.form
```

Output:

```
<POST http://www.gegononta.gr/register.php application/x-www-form-urlencoded
<TextControl(reg_username=)>
<IgnoreControl(reg-checkbutton1=<None>)>
<TextControl(reg_email=)>
<IgnoreControl(reg-checkbutton2=<None>)>
<PasswordControl(reg_password=)>
<PasswordControl(reg_password2=)>
<HiddenControl(recaptcha_response_field=manual_challenge)>
<SubmitControl(submit=Create user)>
<HiddenControl(regfrom=full)>>
```

How can I fill in the following field?

```
<textarea cols="40" rows="3" name="recaptcha_challenge_field"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea cols="40" rows="3" name="recaptcha_challenge_field"></textarea>
```

is actually not a field that mechanize can fill out.

Comment: But for what reason? I see it as being no different to the rest, other than being in a noscript tag. And seeing as though mechanize doesn't use JS, it should work, right?